# VBA- Add timestamp each time button is clicked in same row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and need some help. So far I've been able to create a userform that saves a timestamp of each time a button is clicked. This is the format on the worksheet:

| Time | User | Sample | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "hh:mm:ss" | name | 000 | sweet |

The table also stores when the "Start" button is clicked under the Attribute column. Buttons may or not be clicked, and they could be clicked multiple times. I would like to calculate the time difference for button clicks using the timestamp for "Start" as a reference, controlling for each user and sample combination. I know there is a DateDiff function, but not sure how to use it in this case.
This is what I would like to have:
[Data setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN5OF.png)

This is the code for the Start button:

```
    Private Sub CmmdBtnStart_Click()
    'Close form after 30 seconds from clicking Start
    countdown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Application.OnTime countdown, "UnloadIt"
   
    'Add timestamp of Start Button
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim BtnStart As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")

    With wsData
    lastrow = wsData.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    BtnStart = CmmdBtnStart.Caption
    End With

    With wsData
    'Add time it was clicked
        With .Cells(lastrow, 1)
             .Value = Now
             .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        'Add user name
        .Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = txtboxuser.Value
        'Add sample code
        .Cells(lastrow, 3).Value = txtboxsample.Value
        'Get button caption or text and add to worksheet
        .Cells(lastrow, 4).Value = BtnStart
    End With

    End Sub
```

Each button has a similar code to add data to worksheet. Do I need a code in the userform, or could this be accomplished in the worksheet?
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Times are only numbers in Excel, you can just subtract one from the other. The rest is just formatting.

Comment: If each user has only one start time you could use SUMIFS to find the appropriate one and deduct that from the time the button is clicked.